# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have shape (128, 128, 1) but got array with shape (128, 128, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm building a CNN that can classify greyscale CT images as positive for pneumonia or negative. (Binary image classifier), but when I run the model it gives this error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have shape (128, 128, 1) but got array with shape (128, 128, 3)

Here is the first conv2D layer;
`model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(128,128,1), filters=64, kernel_size=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu"))`

I changed my input shape to 128, 128, 1 so I don't understand what the issue is. If any extra code is needed to help with gaining further insight into the issue, please let me know.

Comment: You changed the input shape of the convolution, but did you convert your image to grayscale? It seems like you might still have RGB channels in the image you're passing in.

Comment: @Chrispresso Thanks for pointing it out! I added color_mode = 'grayscale' to .flow_from_directory and it fixed it.